# How to run a java applet and swing program in eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, applet

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.fillRect(20, 50, 10, 100);

}

}
```

Tell me how to execute this code in eclipse

Comment: Look at `WindowBuilder` https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.windowbuilder

Answer (score 0):

Try the standard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>